# unexpected keyword_do_block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following snippet works fine with my Rails 3.0.3:

```
class Lab1pd1amController < ApplicationController
  def index
     respond_to do |format|
     @students = Student.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.session = 'AM' and students.pd1 = 'Science' ORDER BY lname ASC")
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @students }
    end
  end

 def show
   @students = Student.find(params[:all])

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @student }
    end
 end
end
```

But when I deploy with using Heroku, I get the following syntax error message (on Heroku logs):

> /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3
>   .0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/controllers/lab1pd1am_controller.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that something didn't sneak in there before you did a `git push heroku master`.

It could use some cleaning up as well.

```
class Lab1pd1amController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @students = Student.where(:session => "AM", :pd1 => "Science").order("lname ASC")

     respond_to do |format|         
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @students }
    end
  end

 def show
   @student = Student.find(params[:all])

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @student }
    end
 end
end
```

You could also swap out the `respond_to`'s for the `respond_to/respond_with` combo to clean it up a bit more.

Comment: Hey Adam,  After following your instructions, this is what I got: